# How to configure DHCP client options in RHEL7?

Tags: redhat, dhcp, rhel7

I have a RedHat 7 server with a couple of network interfaces. One of those is DHCP enabled.

```
DEVICE=eth4
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
ONBOOT=yes
USERCTL=no
IPV6INIT=no
```

My problem is that it can happen that the DHCP server for that network is not reachable at the time the server boots up. From my understanding, a retry time can be configured?! Is that correct in the first place?

From what I read so far this should be possible in the dhclient-conf (as described [here](https://serverfault.com/a/231286/247455) or [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111971/location-of-dhclient-conf)).

However: I do not find any such config file on my RHEL7. I am not using NetworkManager (uninstalled it). Can anyone share some advice how to configure dhcp client options in RHEL7?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I did not manage to get a dhclient.conf file configured. However, my actual goal, to get DHCP leases even after boot, this parameter in the ifcfg-eth4 did actually work:

> PERSISTENT_DHCLIENT=1

[Source](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-centos-configure-persistent-dhcp-client/)

Now the OS seems to keep checking for a DHCP server as long as it finds one.